# Model trait causing SQL error during insert

Tags: php, laravel

I have an app model that uses a trait. I need the trait to receive some data and using it in the accessor function.

Content model:

```
use App\Traits\ArchiveTrait;

class Content extends Model
{
    use ArchiveTrait;
    protected $fillable = ['title','details'];
    protected $table = 'contents';

    public function getFileName($file_name)
    {
        return $this->archiving->url.'/media/contents/'.$file_name;
    }
}
```

Archive Trait

```
trait ArchiveTrait {
    private $app_id;
    private $archiving;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->app_id = config('archiving.id');
        $this->archiving = Application::findOrFail($this->app_id);
    }

    public function guzzleClient() {
        $headers = [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest',
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->archiving->token,
        ];

        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
            'headers' => $headers,
            'http_errors' => false
        ]);

        return $client;
     }
}
```

Then problem is, when I try to insert a new content, I get the '*Field 'title' and 'details' doesn't have a default value*' SQL error but if I remove the 'use ArchiveTrait' and the getFileName function from the model, then it works just fine. I think there's something wrong with the trait.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Eloquent models get their attributes passed through via the constructor. Because you are overriding the constructor and not passing anything to the parent constructor, the attributes of your model are never set.

You shouldn't add a constructor in a trait, but if you really needed to, you could fix this by passing the `$attributes` variable to the parent constructor:

```
public function __construct($attributes = [])
{
    parent::__construct($attributes);

    $this->app_id = config('archiving.id');
    $this->archiving = Application::findOrFail($this->app_id);
}
```

Comment: is there another way of running the code without using construct ? I need the code to run automatically

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to achieve